# Placement of floats defined in supporting files

Tags: floats

I would like to separate my main document and floats (tables and figure). Here, the floats would be defined in a separate file or multiple files, often using an order or structure that is unrelated to how they would occur in text. For example, imagine this kind of structure:

```
main-text.tex
density-plots.tex
summary-tables.tex
sample-tables.tex
```

The problem is now how to include all these floats and place them where they should go. Ideally, it would be great if floats were placed close to where they are first referenced, with a more fine-grained control via a `\placefloat{label}` command or something like that. One option of course would be having each float in a separate file and then `\input` it where needed, but I'd like to have some more flexibility.

Is there a package that provides this sort of functionality? I am aware of the `endfloat` package that kind of does the opposite. There is also [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362533/separating-definition-and-placement-of-a-figure/362693#362693) that illustrates how this kind of functionality could be approached but I was hoping for a more automatic and complete existing solution.

Comment: If you put each float into its own file an use the label also as file name, `\placefloat{label}` could be replaced by `\input{label}`. So I do not see, why `\input` is not flexible enough.

Comment: @cabohah Yes, that's the one way to go (as mentioned), but I am enquiring about possibility of defining multiple figures per file.